# Why are my inserted model's id not a string, and how to search with that value?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I tested saving a document in MongoDB, and realized that the `_id` is not a string, but an object as `{ _str: "57aa1b4ea70ce79ff699fa17" }`

What's up with that? Why isn't it a string?

### *** Edit

How do I search with this value? For example :

```
let id = 'ObjectID("57aa1b4ea70ce79ff699fa17")';

return FooCollection.find( id );  // ??? returns nothing!
```

The `ìd` value is passed by the client (i.e. `model._id`) to a subscription, and I need to filter a collection with that value. However, it returns nothing, obviously (?).

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/meteor-talk/f-ljBdZOwPk/oQYZQxCAKN8J

Comment: https://forums.meteor.com/t/convert-meteor-mongo-string--id-into-objectid/19782

Answer (score 0):

### Suppose We have 2 documents in mongoDB:

```
/* 1 */
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("57ac2e768408012ccd000c7f"),
  "max" : "3.4.6",
  "min" : "1.10.2"
}

/* 2 */
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("57ac2e768408012ccd000c80"),
  "max" : "10.9.12",
  "min" : "6.90.1"
}
```

### (1)If you are using Node.JS & Mongoose, it is ok to query _id by string. For example in node.Js:

```
var model = testModel.getTestModel(conn);

    var query = {
        _id: '57ac2e768408012ccd000c7f'
    };


    model
            .find(query)
            .exec(function(err, docs) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    console.log(docs);
                    mongoHelper.disconnectMongoDB(conn);
                }
            });
```

Then the output is:

```
[ { min: '1.10.2', max: '3.4.6', _id: 57ac2e768408012ccd000c7f } ]
mongo connection closed
```

### (2)But if you are using mongoDB Shell, you need to use **ObjectId** -- A special object type in mongoDB which contains a unique hex string

```
db.test.find({
    _id: ObjectId('57ac2e768408012ccd000c7f')
});
```